# Affine coordinate ring $A(X)$ and ring of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$: Isomorphism or equality?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question on the equality of the ring of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ on $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ and the affine coordinate ring $A(X)$. Some sources state it is as an isomorphism (Harthshorne, chapter 1, theorem 3.2), others as an equality (A. Gathmann 2002/3, algebraic geometry, online pdf, proposition 2.1.10). What is actually correct, or rather more precise? Secondly, on a more specific level, I wondered the following. Assume that $h\in A(X)$ is non-zero on all of $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$. Then $1/h\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Does this equality (or rather seen as an isomorphism) imply that $1/h$ is in $A(X)$, i.e. actually can be seen (somehow) as a polynomial (in $A(X)$)?

Comment: It just depends on your definitions. That doesn't have anything to do with your question about $\frac{1}{h}$, which is in $A(X)$ but is not a "polynomial" in the strict sense that the pullback map from regular functions on $\mathbb{A}^n$ is not necessarily surjective.

Comment: So you are saying that there are differences in the definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ in different sources? I am not quite sure in what way these definitions are not equal.

Comment: The separate question regarding $1/h$ also still puzzles me. How can I see that this is in fact in $A(X)=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I(X)$.

Comment: If $h$ has no zero in $X$ then it is not contained in any maximal ideal of $A(X)$ so it is a unit ie. $1/h$ is in $A(X)$ (in a commutative unital ring $R$ any non-unit element $r$ is such that $R/(r)$ is not the zero quotient ring so this quotient ring contains a maximal ideal, giving a maximal ideal of $R$ containing $r$)

Comment: @user823: that definition of the affine coordinate ring is only correct if $X$ is closed. Do you want to assume this? Otherwise consider $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$, whose ring of regular functions is $k[x, x^{-1}]$. As for the first question, again, it depends on your definitions, specifically your definition of $A(X)$. You could just define it to be the ring of regular functions and then they are definitionally equal. Or you could be defining affine varieties as the Spec of their coordinate rings and then there's something to check.

Comment: @user823 Perhaps before we can answer your questions, you should ask yourself this more basic question: is $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ literally a subset of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, or merely isomorphic to the subset $\{ 0/1, 1/1, 2/1, \ldots \}$?

Comment: @ZhenLin I am not sure, but I believe that $\mathbb{N}$ is not even a group, so can it be a isomorphism between any algebraic structure? On the other hand, I see also a difference, in terms of how the sets $\{0/1,1/1,2/1,...\}=\{(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),...\}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are formed, but I am not completely sure where this is going....

Comment: If I am writing $1/h$ as a pair $(1,h)$ and I suppose that $h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$, being a unit, $(1,h)=(h^{-1},1)$ where $h^{-1}h\equiv 1\mod I(X)$. Why it is a unit is clear from the above comments.

Comment: @hm2020 on page 3 in Hartshorne, affine varieties are defined as irreducible closed subets of  $\mathbb{A}^n$. Theorem 3.2 relates to affine varieties, I believe it excludes quasi-affine varieties, but if you "extend" the notion of affine varieties a bit to include quasi-affine varieties, as in other sources, by the mentioned isomorphism you can in fact find an isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}(X)$ and $A(Z(ft-1))$ using this embedding. But I think, we cannot say $A(X)\cong A(Z(ft-1)), t=1/f$, since we have no well-defined isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, Theorem 3.2 speaks of affine varieties, but the ring $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is defined for any quasi affine variety, hence it makes sense to speak of this ring for $X=D(f)$. In the embedding $u$ it follows $D(f)$ is quasi affine, but in the embedding $v$ it follows $D(f)\cong V(tf-1)$ is affine defined by the polynomial $tf-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I am addressing the second part of the question first. The initial part of the question follows directly from this explanation.

Let $X$ be an affine variety with affine coordinate ring $A(X)=A/I(X)$ with $A$ being the polynomial ring in
$n$ variables.  Furthermore, let $\mathcal{O}(X)$ be the ring of regular functions on $X$.  Consider the non-maximal and non-zero ideal $I(X)\subset A$, which is prime by the irreducibility of $X$. Subsequently, it is known that  $I(X)$ is contained in all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_P$, where $P\in X$. For $P\not\in X$, we have $I(X)\not\subset\mathfrak{m}_P$. It is claimed in R. Hartshorne, theorem 3.2 (a) that $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong A(X)$. The isomorphism $\psi:\mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow A(X)$ obviously maps polynomials in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ to polynomials in $A(X)$, i.e. $r\mapsto r+I(X)$, with $r\in A$. What happens to non-polynomial  regular functions in $\mathcal{O}(X)$? Let $f/g\in \mathcal{O}(X)$ with $f,g\in A$ and $g$ non-zero on $X$. It can be shown that $g+I(X)$ has a multiplicative inverse in $A(X)$. Which elements in $A(X)$ have a multiplicative inverse?  The maximal ideals of $A(X)$ are precisely $\mathfrak{m}_P$ with $P\in X$, i.e. all elements in $A(X)\setminus\bigcup_{P\in X}\mathfrak{m}_P$ have an inverse in $A(X)$, as  $A(X)/\mathfrak{m}_P=A(\{P\})$ is a field by basic rules of commutative algebra. Any non-zero element of $A(\{P\})$ has an inverse in $A(\{P\})$. Now note that $\mathcal{O}(X)$ contains only regular functions with denominators which are non-zero on $X$, therefore $g+I(X)\not\in \bigcup_{P\in X}\mathfrak{m}_P$  for $g\not\in I(X)$, so $g+I(X)$ must have a multiplicative inverse in $A(X)$. Call this inverse $h+I(X)\in A(X)$, then let $1/g\mapsto h+I(X)$. Summarising, we have $$\psi:\mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow A(X) \\ f/g\mapsto fh+I(X),$$ where $h$ is a representative of the multiplicative inverse of $g+I(X)$ in $A(X)$, whose existence was demonstrated in the above discussion.

Is this map so described bijective? The surjectivity follows simply from $f/1\mapsto f+I(X)$. On the other hand, assume  $\psi(f_1/g_1)=\psi(f_1/g_2)$, which implies by the above mapping $f_1h_1+I(X)=f_2h_2+I(X)$ with $f_1h_1+I(X),f_2h_2+I(X)$ being multiplicative inverses of $g_1+I(X),g_2+I(X)$, respectively, in $A(X)$.  Clearly, $f_1h_1$ and $f_2h_2$ differ by an element of $I(X)$, so in an evaluation  $(f_1/g_1)(P)=(f_2/g_2)(P)$ for $P\in X$, which implies that $f_1/g_1|_X=f_2/g_2|_X$. On the other hand, by the above rule, $f_1h_1$ also maps to $f_1h_1+I(X)$. Is $f_1h_1|_X=f_1/g_1|_X$, as well? For any evaluation at any $P\in X$, we know that $(h_1g_1+I(X))(P)=(1+I(X))(P)$. But then $h_1g_1-1\in I(X)$, which implies the equality $1/g_1=h_1$ on $X$, as $g_1$ is non-zero on
$X$. The homomorphism property is obvious, as we use the natural homomorphism.

As an additional remark, two regular functions $l_1,l_2$ can be identical on the closed subvariety $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$, but differ on an appropriately chosen open subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$. This is the case, if $l_1-l_2\in I(X)$. Take as a simple example $X=Z((y^2-x))$ and $l_1=1$ and $l_2=\frac{1}{y^2-x+1}$. Clearly, $l_1|_X=l_2|_X$.

Now the questions are simple to answer. Yes, we can say $\mathcal{O}(X)=A(X)$ if we consider the equalities of certain regular functions under a restriction to $X$. The answer to the second part of the question follows directly from the determination of the multiplicative inverse in accordance with the above derivation of this inverse.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Secondly, on a more specific level, I wondered the following. Assume that $h\in A(X)$ is non-zero on all of $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$. Then $1/h\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Does this equality (or rather seen as an isomorphism) imply that $1/h$ is in $A(X)$, i.e. actually can be seen (somehow) as a polynomial (in $A(X)$)?"

**Answer:** This example illustrates that it is not possible to define the notion "polynomial function" on a quasi affine variety.

Let $X:=V(I) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_k$ be an affine variety defined by the prime ideal $I \subseteq k[x_1,..,x_n]$ with $k$ a field (in the sense of Hartshorndes book Ch I).

By definition $A:=\mathcal{O}(X)$ is the ring of regular functions on $X$ (in the sense of HH Def. Ch3) and since any polynomial $f∈k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is a regular function, you get a canonical injective map $j:A(X)→A$ which is proved in HH Thm3.2 to be an isomorphism. It does not make much sense to use the word "equality" since $A$ is defined up to isomorphism, hence I agree with HHs terminology: The map $j$ is an isomorphism.

If $u:X:=D(f)⊆\mathbb{A}^n_k$ is the complement of the hypersurface $H:=V(f)$ it follows $f$ is never zero on X and $1/f∈\mathcal{O}(X)$ is a well defined regular function, which is not a polynomial function in the embedding $u$. In the embedding u it follows $X$ is quasi affine, but it is an affine variety using another embedding: $v:X≅V(tf−1)⊆\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$.

In the embedding $v$ it follows $1/f=t$ which is a "polynomial function".

Hence being a "polynomial function" is not well defined - in the embedding $u$ it is not a polynomial function, in the embedding $v$ it is a polynomial function. The ring of regular functions $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is an invariant of $X$ and does not depend on the embedding.

**Question:** "Assume that $h\in A(X)$ is non-zero on all of $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$. Then $1/h\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Does this equality (or rather seen as an isomorphism) imply that $1/h$ is in $A(X)$, i.e. actually can be seen (somehow) as a polynomial (in $A(X)$)?"

**Anwer:** If $X:=V(I)$ is an affine variety, there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong A(X)$ (HHThm3.2) hence this is immediate.